# Sudoers: Allow any subcommand for certain argument

Tags: sudo, administration

I'm trying to allow a group of users to gain some control over an instance of a dhcpcd service. In other words I would like to have them be able to run:

```
systemctl (start,stop,...) dhcpcd@eth0.service
```

without being prompted for a password but only on dhcpcd@eth0.service. I have already come across ways of doing that, however they require enumeration of every subcommand in its own line.

```
%mygroup ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl start dhcpcd@eth0.service, /usr/bin/systemctl stop dhcpcd@eth0.service, ...
```

Is there a more elegant method of doing this?

Comment: Also, systemd can use PolicyKit to authenticate users, and it offers more granular control than plain sudo. [Here's an example on how to achieve exactly what you want](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit#Allow_management_of_individual_systemd_units_by_regular_users).

Comment: I had a look at policykit, and found where I could implement the required behaviour with my own regex. But my lack of confidence in my regex being explicit and modifying a new part of the system made me favour a small enumeration / shell script method. Thank you for your suggestion, now I know another method to control user policies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sudoers wildcards are only supported with globbing (`man glob`, `man fnmatch`).  Yet, the `start`, `stop`, `restart` (, etc.) commands for `systemctl` cannot be globbed since they are not files.

The fact that you need to enumerate every command is a good thing from a security standpoint.  If `dhcpcd@eth0.service` is updated with a command, say `shutdown-machine` on a system update your sudo users will not be able to use it (thankfully).

There is a note about this in the sudoers manual:

```
 Wildcards in command line arguments should be used with care.
 Command line arguments are matched as a single, concatenated string.  This mean a wildcard character such as ‘?’ or
 ‘*’ will match across word boundaries, which may be unexpected.  For example, while a sudoers entry like:

     %operator ALL = /bin/cat /var/log/messages*

 will allow command like:

     $ sudo cat /var/log/messages.1

 It will also allow:

     $ sudo cat /var/log/messages /etc/shadow

 which is probably not what was intended.  In most cases it is better to do command line processing outside of the
 sudoers file in a scripting language.
```

On the other hand, if you want to save on typing you can do exactly what the manual suggests: use a scripting language.  For example you could wirte something like this in, say, `/usr/local/sbin/sudoers-dhcpd.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
  start)
    systemctl start dhcpcd@eth0.service
    ;;
  stop)
    systemctl stop dhcpcd@eth0.service
    ;;
  restart)
    systemctl restart dhcpcd@eth0.service
    ;;
  *)
    echo You are not allowed to do that!
    ;;
esac
```

And add a sudoers line as follows:

```
%mygroup ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/sudoers-dhcpd.sh
```

Comment: You could also add a case with `start|stop|restart)` and use `$1` in the command.  But from the security standpoint you're then depending that there are no exploitable bugs in the `|` operator in the `case` matches.

Comment: Or just define the exact 3 specific commands allowed in sudoers without any wildcards.  Just as OP described.   It may not be elegant but it is secure.